# How to add Mura's Comment form to a Mura Template

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I would like to add Mura's comment form to a template on my Mura site.  However, Mura's documentation only explains how to do so page by page via the inline editor.

I have scoured the web and come up empty handed for an example of how to do this.

How to I include Mura's comment form on my templates without having to write something custom from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

This is from Mura version 6.2 but it should work similarly in newer versions. After enabling the Comment module as documented [here for v6](https://docs.getmura.com/v6/content-managers/comments-manager/) and [here for v7](http://docs.getmura.com/v7-1/content-managers/advanced-content/#section-managing-comments). You just need to add the object to the layout of your page from the admin. You will find the "Accept Comments" object under the "System" content objects (see the screenshot below). Once you do that then inheritance will apply the same to any child pages and they too will have the comment option.

[image]